# Solve Expression in function of a variable t

Tags: equation-solving, expression-manipulation

I have this expression on Mathematica.

```
Expr = Sqrt[Cosh[t]^2 Sinh[t]^2 + (1/2 + Sinh[t]^2)^2 - 
2 Sqrt[Cosh[t]^2 Sinh[t]^2 (1/2 + Sinh[t]^2)^2]] == 0.5
```

How Can I find a solution in function of t for this expression using Mathematica?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's an inequality, no? Anyway, try the substitution `t -> 2 ArcTanh[u]`.

Comment: Sorry, I typed wrong, the correct is == 0.5

Comment: You mean like this? `eq=Sqrt[Cosh[t]^2 Sinh[t]^2+(1/2+Sinh[t]^2)^2-2 Sqrt[Cosh[t]^2 Sinh[t]^2 (1/2+Sinh[t]^2)^2]]==1/2;
Solve[eq,t,Reals]` and this gives `t->0`

Answer (score 1):

`FindRoot` will also work here,

For a good initial guess, first plot your equation,

```
Plot[Expr, {t, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

And then use in it `FindRoot`

```
FindRoot[Expr, {t, 0}]
```

> {t -> 0.}